# jQuery.ajax not working in any IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, jquery

My code below does not work in IE10 (or before) at my work computer but seems to works fine on my home computer.  I don't think it is even making the request, as I set breakpoints around it and see nothing in the network tab.  I have read a lot about caching issues with $.ajax in IE and have tried cache busters and $.get, etc. but I dont think that is the issue.  You can see this live at timmygcentral.com (script is in loadReccomendations function in index.html).  It has to be some security issue (because it only happens on my work network in IE, it works fine on my work network in Chrome/FF and works fine on my home network in all browsers).

```
var tgc_recommendations_uri = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AsRjUFPfaIWvdGxPT3U0ZGRNUnFGakwwQnpKQi1Hbnc/od6/public/values?alt=json";
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: tgc_recommendations_uri,
  format: "jsonp",
  success: function(data){
    $('#recCarousel').css('opacity','0')
    var template = "...";
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data.feed);
  }
});
```

Comment: Since you are using jsonp, it shouldn't be a cross-domain issue. contentType can be left off since it's jsonp, and if it is failing you'll see an error in your console. Also, `format: "jsonp"` should be `dataType: "jsonp"`

Comment: Nice! Replacing format with dataType worked!

Answer (score 0):

Include `async:false` in your ajax

Like this

```
var tgc_recommendations_uri = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0AsRjUFPfaIWvdGxPT3U0ZGRNUnFGakwwQnpKQi1Hbnc/od6/public/values?alt=json";
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  type: "GET",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: tgc_recommendations_uri,
  format: "jsonp",
  async:false,
  success: function(data){
  $('#recCarousel').css('opacity','0')
  var template = "...";
  var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data.feed);
}
});
```

Comment: How does `async:false` help?

Comment: When you remove `async` behavior somewhere a few bunnies maybe some puppies die. Don't do that plz

Comment: That didnt work anyway. Could it be a cross-domain issue?  Nothing comes up in console or anything.

Comment: If you are requesting cross-domain, then jsonp should be the proper setting.